# Accessing an external library callback in an Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an external library (http://support.video.limelight.com/support/docs/player_api/) that calls the function `limelightPlayerCallback()` every time something with the player changes.

I want to be able to trigger actions in my Angular controller every time the library calls that function. When I declare the function in my HTML, everything works as expected.

```
function limelightPlayerCallback (playerId, eventName, data){
 console.log(playerId);
 console.log(eventName);
 console.log(data);
}
```

Gets me

```
player1
onPlayerLoad
null
```

And also allows me to access the `LimelightPlayer` object and run queries and commands on it like.

```
LimelightPlayer.doGetPlayheadPositionInMilliseconds()
LimelightPlayer.doLoadMedia()
```

But once I start trying to declare the `limelightPlayerCallback()` function in my controller, or access the `LimelightPlayer` object, the function is never called so I am not able to interact with the player at all.

What is the best way to go about interfacing with a library that works like this in Angular?

Comment: It likely has to be defined globally in order for the 3rd party thing to call it. Due to this, defining it in your controller won't work unless you also assign it to window.

Comment: Would there possibly be a way of calling an angular function from within limelightPlayerCallback like function `limelightPlayerCallback (playerId, eventName, data){
angularCallback(playerId,eventName,data);
}`

Comment: Yup, that's just a javascript function, nothing angular about it.

Comment: when I tried to access a controller method from the callback it doesn't seem to run the video.limelight() function. `<div ng-controller="VideoController as video">
  <script>
    function limelightPlayerCallback (playerId, eventName, data){
      video.limelight(playerId,eventName,data);
    }
  </script>`